# phpMyAdmin userbased host

Tags: phpmyadmin

Hi I wanna use userbased hosts within config.inc.php like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'std.host.org';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

if ($_POST['pma_username'] =='specialuser')
{
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'my.database.org';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '1234';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
}
```

It is not working, any ideas?

Comment: In what ways is it not working[?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: database connection not established ("Cannot log in to the MySQL server"). user, pass, port, etc is fine

Comment: There's no code here that connects to the database. Can you add that? We're not psychic, so it's only possible to comment on what you show.

Comment: sorry for that... this is from the std config.inc.php. don't know where the snippet is where phmMyAdmin connects to the database.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a supported configuration.

You can configure [multiple hosts](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/multiserver), but it's global across that phpMyAdmin instance and users must then select the proper server from the dropdown menu. Or you could install two different phpMyAdmin instances, one for std.host.org and one for my.database.org, and then have your users bookmark the correct page for their use.